# cameraKit-android output video

Tags: android, android-camera

Does anyone use the CameraKit-Android by gogopop? My problem is that I set the listener of video but the outputfile is `null`. Anyone know how to solve it?

this is my code:

```
        cameraView.getCamera().setVideoQuality(CameraKit.Constants.VIDEO_QUALITY_720P);
        cameraView.getCamera().startRecordingVideo();
        cameraView.getCamera().setCameraListener(new CameraListener() {
            @Override
            public void onVideoTaken(final File video) {
                super.onVideoTaken(video);
            /*    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        final byte[] videoBytes = FileUtils.File2byte(video.getAbsolutePath());
                        if (!isExit) {
                            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    saveFile(videoBytes);
                                }
                            }).start();
                        }
                        isExit = false;
                    }
                }).start();*/
            }
        });
```

I've used to make a new file to save the mp4, but when I'm recording a video longer than one minute, the app is OOM. Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i slove it. this is not cameraKit-android issuse. it is the Android 's problem,it have two point:

1. the file is exit, but you don't notification the system. so you should :

   ```
         cameraView.getCamera().setCameraListener(new CameraListener() {
           @Override
           public void onVideoTaken(final File video) {
               super.onVideoTaken(video);
               //notify system refresh
               Uri localUri = Uri.fromFile(video);
               Intent localIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, localUri);
               sendBroadcast(localIntent);
   ```
2. try this guys idea, i use it save susscess:

   ```
   String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/milai/";

   File appDir = new File(path);

   if (!appDir.exists()) {
       appDir.mkdir();
   }
   mVideoFile = new File(mPreview.getView().getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null), getPicTime()+".mp4");
   String myFile = path+getPicTime()+".mp4";
   mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(myFile);
   ```

it look the same , but i don't know why success. if eveybody have other problem, can ask me . i will try to help you.

Comment: U have any solution for that ??

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this problem;

```
  public static void saveVideoToFile( File video) {
        try {

            File newfile;

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(video);
            File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "Your File Name" + "/");
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }

            newfile = new File(dir, "save_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4");

            if (newfile.exists()) newfile.delete();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newfile);
            // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;

            while ((len = fileInputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }

            fileInputStream.close();
            out.close();

            MyLog.log("Copy file successful.");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```